# Filling the outside of selected Hull Convex with black?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I created a convex hull of a hand from an X-ray. I did this by first creating contours along the edges of the hand. I am wanting to blacken the outside region of convex hull using OpenCV in Python. How do I approach this?

The code below creates the convex hull after doing contours:

```
img_path = 'sample_image.png'

# Getting the threshold of the image:
image = cv2.imread(img_path)
original = image.copy() 
blank = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype = np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 140, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Drawing the contours along the edges of the hand in X-ray:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = max(contours, key = lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x))
cv2.drawContours(image, [contours], -1, (255,255,0), 2)

# Drawing the hull along the digits along the edges: 
hull = cv2.convexHull(contours)
cv2.drawContours(image, [hull], -1, (0, 255, 255), 2)
```

Input image: [Sample_image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvbZl.jpg)

Result image: [Output from the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9910.jpg)

### Update

Answer given by @AKX below proposed to draw the contour with filled polygon onto a new white blank and then use `bitwise_and`. The result code:

```
# Merge text into a single contour
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations = 2)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = max(contours, key = lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x))

cv2.drawContours(image, [contours], -1, (255,255,0), 2)
plt.imshow(image)

# Created a new mask and used bitwise_and to select for contours:
hull = cv2.convexHull(contours)
mask = np.zeros_like(image)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [hull], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)
masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask)

plt.imshow(masked_image)
```

Comment: Could you also post your `sample_image.png`?

Comment: Ooops my apologies for not uploading the original image. I edited the post with an original sample image :) @AKX

Comment: Nah, it's alright! I put my doodling skills to great use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Masking

Instead of drawing the hull contour as a line, draw it as a filled polygon onto a blank image with white, then `bitwise_and` it onto the original so everything outside the polygon is blanked out.

```
mask = np.zeros_like(image)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [hull], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)
masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask)
cv2.imwrite(r'dog_masked.jpg', masked_image)
```

### input image

(no idea why I called it dog.jpg, it doesn't look like a dog)

[image]

### result

(the line below the dog remains since it's inside the hull created by the dog's feet)

[image]

## Cropping

To crop the image to only include the hull's area, use `cv2.boundingRect` and slice the image array:

```
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(hull)
cropped = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
cv2.imwrite(r'dog_crop.jpg', cropped)
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: I tried with my sample image and super glad it worked :) Thank you so so much! My approach was to have hull convex and color in the outside of whatever of convex with black.

Comment: Do you perhaps also know how to only save the selected hand from an X-ray as a new image? So save only the selected hand from an hull convex? @AKX

Comment: Oh, sure. That would ordinarily be another question, but it's not a big addition here...

Comment: @Leisure_is_Pleasure Please see edit. :-)

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. I thought you had to use cv2.getPerspectiveTransform, get the image's source and dst points and then use cv2.warpPerspective to get the final warped image. This is super simple and nice thank you once again :)

Comment: No worries. If you need, you can use `boxPoints` to get the angle of a rotated bounding box for the hand, and use it to rotate the cropped image if you want to straighten it. See https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html (search for Rotated Rectangle).